# Which is the Num key on the keyboard?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Text editors such as EditPlus and Notepad++ have keyboard shortcuts like:

```
Ctrl+Num +

Ctrl+Num -

Alt+Shift+Num +

Alt+Shift+Num -
```

Where's the `Num` key on the standard QWERTY English keyboard? I use a Lenovo Ideapad Z560 laptop.

Comment: it can refer to a number positioned at the right most part of your keyboard (the number pad) or to Num Lock itself.

Comment: Thank you. You were quite close and your answer actually helped me figure it out.

Comment: i just noticed i said "number positioned", when i really meant "key positioned". good you sorted it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, it likely refers to the <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> keys of the numeric keypad:

[image: Lenovo Ideapad Z560 keyboard]

Comment: You are a hero! I'd figured it out from Lorenzo's comment above after some trial and error, but the quality of your answer is just superb, so I have to vote you up. Thank you very much. :-)

Comment: Heh, beat me to it and with the same image :)

Answer (score 6):

There is no <kbd>Num</kbd> button. The shortcuts mean the <kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>-</kbd> that is on the *number pad* ([image source](http://www.elitepvpers.com/forum/crossfire-hacks-bots-cheats-exploits/2337804-new-year-hack.html)):

[image]

If this image of an Z560 keyboard that I found online is correct, the buttons you are looking for are circled in red ([image source](http://www.notebook.gen.tr/img/modeller/Lenovo-IBM-IdeaPad-Z560-Z560-59-044260_3.jpg)):

[image]

Comment: Awesome answer. Thank you very much! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Num+ / Num- probably means the Plus or Minus Key on the [Numpad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numpad). If you don't have a separate Numpad on your Notebook, you have to use another Key (in most cases it's labeled `Fn`) in conjuntion with that QWERTY-Key which is labeled + or - in the *upper right* corner.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's "Num Lock."  You can test this by opening up any shortcut with right click --> Properties --> shortcut tab --> Click in the "Short cut Key" field and use the combination you want. It should then populate with the text, such as, "Ctrl + Num Lock."

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Lenovo Laptop, which do not have the numeric key pad.
`Ctrl+Num +` and `Ctrl+Num -` keys are used to zoom in and zoom out the text in notpad++.
In lenovo laptops one can mimic the functionality by using inbuilt red mouse scroll up and scroll down with ctrl key combination.